# Send email with Powershell from different mailbox

Tags: email, powershell, outlook

I have created a small PS script to create an email for my pipeline to send out whenever there is a deployment. the problem is i dont want the email to be sent from my personal email but from the company outlook email. i searched and saw different SMTP server names and using mail.from but i cant get it to work. can someone help me out?

```
 param(
[Parameter(Mandatory=$true,Position=0)]
[string]$Address1,
[Parameter(Mandatory=$true,Position=1)]
[string]$Address2,
[switch]$Recurse,
[switch]$Force  
)

 $ol = New-Object -comObject Outlook.Application  
 $mail = $ol.CreateItem(0)  
 $Mail.Recipients.Add($Address1) 
$Mail.Recipients.Add($Address2) 
$Mail.Subject = "DSC Deployment in Progress"  
$Mail.Body = "There is a DSC install beginning. . ."  
$Mail.Send()
```

Comment: Hi, can you access both email accounts in your Outlook client ?

Comment: i dont think so, i only see settings for my personal email, for what its worth i belong to that specific group that i want the email to be sent from

Comment: Try with `Send-MailMessage`, then. You can specify an SMTP server with it. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.utility/send-mailmessage

Comment: What's the distinction between "*personal email*" and "*company outlook email*", if your code which automates outlook actually sends personal email?

Comment: thanks yes i came across that method but cant figure out what my smtp server is for outlook

Comment: @tessel, so basically the code works sending the email from my personal outlook, but my team has its own email which id like to have on the outgoing message instead of mine

Comment: Do you have permission to 'send-as' the team email account from within your Outlook? If you write a new email by hand, can you choose to send from the team address?

Comment: hi yes! i can sorry for the wait

Comment: edit: i came across something like this but dont know how it works        function Send-mail($msg) {
    $_from = "company email"
    $_to = "address1"

Answer (score 4):

You need to assign a value to the `SendUsingAccount` property. The account can be found in the `(outlook).Session.Accounts` collection.

```
$sendSmtpAddress = "some.name@somedomain.com"
$account = $ol.session.acounts | ? { $_.smtpAddress -eq $sendSmtpAddress }
```

then, assign to the SendUsingAccount property before sending

```
$mail.SendUsingAccount = $account
$mail.Send()
```

Full example

```
$sendSmtpAddress = "some.name@somedomain.com"
$ol = new-object -comobject "outlook.application"
$account = $ol.session.accounts | ? { $_.smtpAddress -eq $sendSmtpAddress }
$mail = $ol.CreateItem(0)
$mail.recipients.add("target.user@somedomain.com") | out-null
$mail.subject = "test email"
$mail.body = "test email"
$mail.SendUsingAccount = $account
$mail.Send()
```

For what it's worth, I gave up trying to send email via Outlook a long time ago, it's much easier to use plain SMTP. Depending on the security policy on your local SMTP server (Exchange?), you may be able to 'send as' any user on your local domain. Ask your IT people for the name/IP of an internal SMTP server that you can use to send email, and then it's as easy as:

```
send-mailmessage -smtpServer (servername or IP) -from sender.name@domain.com -to @(recipient1@domain.com, recipient2@domain.com) -subject "Email Subject" -body "Email Body"
```

If using `send-mailmessage`, it's possible to set a Display Name for the sender by using the form `"Display Name <sender.name@domain.com>"` e.g.

```
-from "Deployment Alerts <sender.name@domain.com>"
```

Recipients will see the Display Name in their email client, rather than the SMTP address.

A couple of points that I consider to be good practice:

1. Depending on the config of the SMTP server, there may be little, or no verification of the 'sender' address. It is worth using a genuine account that you have access to, so that you have sight of any bounce / non-delivery reports.
2. Consider including something in the mail body (perhaps a footer) that mentions where the alert came from and what process generated it. This can help your successor or colleague track down the script in the future.

Comment: wow thanks so much that last code of line is much simpler and eaxactly what i needed thanks so much

Comment: No worries Neil, happy it helped. Another technique I use is to set a display name for the sender. This is displayed in the recipient's email client instead of the full SMTP address. I'll update the post to include this.

Answer (score 1):

The assignment like

```
$mail.SendUsingAccount = $account
```

worked for me since Windows Server 2000 till Windows Server 2008 and from Outlook 2007 till Outlook 2016. Since Windows Server 2016 I've got an exception (The server threw an exception. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80010105 (RPC_E_SERVERFAULT))).

But there is an alternative way to assign this property.

```
[Void] $mail.GetType().InvokeMember("SendUsingAccount","SetProperty",$NULL,$mail,$account)
```