# Sending email through powershell issue

Tags: powershell, email, outlook

When i try to send email through powershell im facing following issues
1.Im not able to change the sender as group mailbox
2.it does not read the attachments i add but the mail gets sent.

code im using :

```
    $Outlook = New-Object -ComObject Outlook.Application
    $Mail = $Outlook.CreateItem(0)
    $Mail.To = "xyz@outlook.com"
    $Mail.Subject = "sql"
    $mail.attachments = 'C:\Users\desktop.ini'
    $Mail.Body = ""
    $Mail.Send()
```

error i'm receiving :

```
     Property is read-only.
     At C:\Users\Documents\sending email.ps1:5 char:1
     + $mail.attachments = 'C:\Users\desktop.ini'
     + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (:) [], COMException
     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException
```

But the file is in my local

Comment: Is there a reason to use the Outlook COM object and not [Send-MailMessage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/send-mailmessage)?

Comment: when i add smtp and port details my outlook dosent allow me to send email.so tried alternate method lik this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing an additional parameter

Your script should look something like this:

```
$attachment = "C:\Users\YourUser\Documents\test.txt"    
$mail.attachments.add($attachment)
```

or, if not with a variable

```
$mail.attachments.add("C:\Users\YourUser\Documents\test.txt")
```

As for the group mailbox, the mailbox should be controllable by using

```
$mail.sendusingaccount = "mailbox@company.com"
```

As for adding multiple attachments, you will have to have them in one directory:

```
$getfiles = Get-ChildItem "C:\Users\YourUser\Attachmentfolder\"
Foreach ($getfile in $getfiles) {
$mail.attachments.add($getfile.FullName)
}
```

Comment: So what its worth, I tried it out and could not get it to work for myself sadly. But, some research later, I would advise you in general of using the following:

send-mailmessage -smtpServer (servername or IP) -from sender.name@domain.com -to @(recipient1@domain.com, recipient2@domain.com) -subject "Email Subject" -body "Email Body"

SMTP works like a charm compared to a regular outlook item request. - That is also how I could get it to work then.

Comment: Ill just quickly add you another stackoverflow post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41149684/send-email-with-powershell-from-different-mailbox You can try the outlook-item piece of script, which is recommended by the first answer, but it did not work for me. This might be some other problem on my side though.

Comment: How do i add multiple attachments ?

Comment: $mailobject.attachment.add supports an array, so doing something like $mail.attachments.add("C:Users\YourUser\Documents\test.txt","C:Users\YourUser\Documents\test2.txt","C:Users\YourUser\Documents\test3.txt") should work in theory.

Comment: This did not work...I tried this already.Im getting the below error
        Exception setting "Add": Cannot convert the "C:\Users\Documents\Report\Completed data.xlsx" 
value of type "string" to type "Object".
At line:5 char:1
+ $mail.attachments.add("C:\Users\\Documents\Report\Aged ti ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : RuntimeException

Comment: So I researched a bit and found out that only the send-mailmessage cmdlet accepts arrays for its -attachment parameter. Sorry for that. BUT, of course, I found a way around for you which I added for additional clarity to my initial answer, as you can see. I hope this works for you, because it worked like a charm for me. Good luck! Edit: You will need to delete the $mail.attachments.add($attachments) from outside the foreach loop.